# Run time error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am using windows 7, QGIS version 2.18.19. I tried the following standalone python script.

##Testing=name

### drawingdxf=file

### cleanf=output vector

outputs_GRASS7V_IN_DXF_1=processing.runalg('grass7:v.in.dxf',drawingdxf,'1',True,False,True,False,False,True,['200000.000000,700000.000000,200000.000000,700000.000000'],0,None)
outputs_GRASS7V_CLEAN_1=processing.runalg('grass7:v.clean', outputs_GRASS7V_IN_DXF_1['output'],1,0.1,['200000.000000,700000.000000,200000.000000,700000.000000'],-1.0,0.0001,cleanf,None)

When I am running the program, following error was shown.

**""NoneType' object has no attribute 'getitem See log for more detail"."**

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Replace the periods in the name with something else. E.g. `outputs_GRASSV_IN_DXF_1`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I tried it,but still problem exist